# Можно ли на angular/typescript сделать функцию, которая могла бы возвращать Promise если у неё было вызвано .then либо Observable, при подписке?

Tags: typescript, angular, prototype

Можно ли сделать универсальную функцию, которая бы возвращала промис, если на ней запускают .then() либо же Observable, если на неё подпишутся или такое не делают, а лучше не заморачиваться и написать 2 разных функции?

Comment: функция не знает что будет происходить с результатом вызова. Просто возвращай объект с двумя методами - then и subscribe - и возвращай то что нужно непосредственно в них

Comment: Если отвечать на вопрос, то да, можно. А что пытались сделать вы? Есть примерыы попыток. Что конкретно не получается?